# Calculating percent change between groups using Dplyr - Stock Data

Tags: r, dplyr, stock

Simply trying to calculate the percent change across a given time period for each stock. My current code using dplyr is as follows:

```
stocks_df %>%
filter(Date > now() - days(2)) %>%
group_by(Stock) %>%
mutate(period_return = (Close - first(Close))/ first(Close) * 100) %>%
do(tail(., n=1))


Date       Stock   Close 
2020-02-05 AAPL   308.86 
2020-02-04 AAPL   318.85 
2020-02-03 AAPL   321.45 
2020-02-05 BA     329.55 
2020-02-04 BA     317.94 
2020-02-03 BA     316 
2020-02-05 MSFT   179.9 
2020-02-04 MSFT   180.12 
2020-02-03 MSFT   174.38
```

Desired output would be:

```
AAPL -3.92%
BA   4.29%
MSFT 3.17%
```

Comment: How do you get `-3.96` for `AAPL` ? What is the calculation behind it?

Comment: @RonakShah ((321.45 - 308.86) / 321.45) * 100. Should actually be -3.92, not -3.96

Comment: In addition to @RonakShah's answer, you may be getting different output since you filter out some of your data (based on today's date)...the AAPL price of 321.45 is on Feb. 3 which is more than 2 days ago...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Stock) %>%
  summarise(period_return = -(last(Close) - first(Close))/ last(Close) * 100)

# Stock period_return
#  <fct>         <dbl>
#1 AAPL          -3.92
#2 BA             4.29
#3 MSFT           3.17
```

which can be done in base R using `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Close~Stock, df, function(x) -(x[length(x)] - x[1])/x[length(x)] * 100)
```